# how to add transition effect in between images of video using ffmpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

i want to add trasition effect in video like explod,slide in,slide down,flying out,flying in,quart part in etc..

i used ffmpeg to create video from series of images.but ffmpeg only provide fade in and fade out trasition.if any other way to do that then also tell me.

i spend lots of day but not get any solution.Please help me.

Comment: FFmpeg isn't designed as a video switcher. Your best bet is to compile ffmpeg with this external filter --> https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/ffmpeg-gl-transition

Comment: please give guidelines step by step  to integrate github.com/transitive-bullshit/ffmpeg-gl-transition library in my project.i used com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2 for ffmpeg.

Comment: Instructions are at link in Building section. For compilation, see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Android

Comment: but i have no idea about git setup and how to use in android studio.

Comment: try to run ln -s ~/ffmpeg-gl-transition/vf_gltransition.c libavfilter/ cmd in android studio terminal give error "ln: failed to create symbolic link 'libavfilter/vf_gltransition.c': No such file or directory
"